# How to create a Stacked Column Chart with group data for X axis in Excel?

Tags: excel, dataset

This is chart that I want to generate.

[image]

This is the sample data for Age and Income

```
Age Income
39   <=50K
50   <=50K
38   <=50K
53   <=50K
28   <=50K
37   <=50K
49   <=50K
52   >50K
31   >50K
42   >50K
37   >50K
30   >50K
23   <=50K
32   <=50K
40   >50K
34   <=50K
25   <=50K
32   <=50K
```

Y axis have number of entries and X axis has age group. bar in the chart indicates income that divide into two parts such as greater than $50k and less than or equal to $50k.

I tried to group age and get the chart like above. But it won't generate. Also I followed several tutorials But those could not solve the problem.

Please help! Any help would be appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a data table for the chart, using Countifs

Eg

B1: '<=50
C2: >50
A2: ''17-20
B2: =countif age less than 21 and income is <=50
C2: =countif age less than 21 and income is >50

I hope that helps

Comment: could you please tell me how to write the condition =COUNTIF age less than 21 and income is <=50 .. my dataset has more than 30000 entries

Comment: I got the result using =COUNTIFS instead of =COUNTIF